# Jlist binded from DefaultListModel is it possible to Display Only Certain elements ?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel

Is it possible to bind or show only some of the ListModel or List 
When i Bind it to a Jlist item ?

In my Example I have a list model made from an array of a class(pizza) which has multiple variable's  I only want to show one, but they are all being displayed in a line.

```
  listModel = new DefaultListModel();
  listModel = ListHandler.populateListModel(listModel); 
  // This returns listModel binded from array of a class<Pizza>

  list = new JList(listModel);
  list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
  list.setSelectedIndex(0);
  JScrollPane listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
  Apanel.add(listScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

This code when then display all the items in Pizza per line,
Is it possible to just show 1 varible from pizza ? Cheese for example in the listbox alone... ?

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27372678/filtering-jcombobox/27372985#27372985)?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) BTW - when it comes to filtering, I'd use a [single column `JTable`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28621617/418556).

Comment: @MadProgrammer No Im not trying to filter.. just the the entire output of each class in the list is being dumped line by line(per element) in the Jlist... i would like to only show a varible class .. for example pizza.chesseType or ??elementdata[0].chesseType ?? in the recursive list..

Comment: Then, we'd need to see a runnable example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default cell renderer is calling `toString()` on the value objects in your model. You can do either of these:

- Override/change the value returned by `toString()` to be the text you want to show
- Change the cell renderer to format the value object differently from the default

I'd prefer the second, since you might want `toString()` to have a specific other value for some other reason.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html